# Wait for CSS to load on a nextjs static site?

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components

I have a nextjs static site. As you can see from the screenshot, the JS loads fast but then it waits for the styled-components to apply the CSS. The CSS is applied *after* the page loads.

Any ideas how I can either wait for the styled-components CSS to kick in?

[image: static app]

UPDATE: ah, I forgot that this is a *static* app---that means nextjs will pre-render the output of the page, *and then* load the JS. So it looks like standard techniques to wait for JS to load should apply. HOWEVER...the gotcha is that the static HTML is auto-generated by nextjs, so need a way to do that thru nextjs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Babel-plugin for styled-components => `npm i -D babel-plugin-styled-components`

Then Create pages/_document.js

```
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
```

If you want to use ThemeProvider from styled-components, add the ThemeProvider to pages/_app.js.

[This is an example provided by Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components)

Comment: Awesome dude! Had seen this before but because it's a static app thought it didn't apply. But this fixed it :-)

Comment: This is working perfectly for me. I've been looking for a solution for a quite a while. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a little bit more about what's happening here?